# Running an instance in DEV mode, without displaying exception stacks

Tags: java, playframework, playframework-1.x

I am wondering if I can keep running a Play 1.2.5 instance running in development mode, but without displaying the full exception stack to end users.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two ways:

1. Declare method with @Catch annotation in your controllers:

   ```
   @Catch(Exception.class)
   static void unexpectedErrorOccured(Throwable cause) throws Exception {
       Logger.error(cause, "Unexpected controller error");
       //render whatever you want
   }
   ```
2. Change the template located in `app/views/errors/500.html`